# Has this cartridge of Super 8 film been used or not?

Tags: kodak, processing

I found this Kodak Super 8 cartridge in a box with old photos. Has the film been used or not? If the second picture doesn't tell, how can I find out? It would be nice to know so that I know if I should try to have it processed or not.

[image: Super 8 cartridge - K40 - Kodachrome 40 - movie film - type a[1]
[image: Super 8 cartridge - K40 - Kodachrome 40 - movie film - type a[2]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**It's either unexposed or partially exposed.**

From [tmtv.net's page on old movie film processing](http://www.tmtv.net/additional.html), if the roll was completely exposed, you'd see this:

[image: exposed end of reel]

> "EXPOSED" meaning the film has been shot and ready for processing (developing). DO NOT REMOVE OR ATTEMPT TO OPEN THE CARTRIDGE.
>
> If it does not say "exposed" it was either removed from the Super 8 camera before it was finished or it is a new roll and not exposed, however new rolls are usually in their original sealed package in an unopened box.

While color Kodachrome processing was officially discontinued at the end of 2010, you may still find a lab that can process it as a black and white negative, like [this one](http://www.spectrafilmandvideo.com/Lab.html).

Answer (score 2):

Super 8 movie film remains in use. However, the film inside your cassette is Kodak Kodachrome. This is a discontinued color film that required special processing. Sorry to report that the special process is no longer available. You are strongly advised not to use this film. You might choose to keep it and put it on display or donate it to a museum. I don't believe anyone will pay you so donate.

Comment: I suppose I didn't ask the question clearly enough. The question is if that particular cartridge in the picture has been used or not. I'm wondering if I need to develop it or if it hasn't been used before.

Comment: I think Alan's point is that since you ***can't*** have it developed anywhere, it's a moot point — if it was shot and not developed, it's probably lost, and if it isn't, you shouldn't put yourself through the trouble. You may want to try developing it as black and white at home — I've seen [reports](https://waybackman.wordpress.com/2015/06/04/developing-40-year-old-kodachrome/) of people doing that. (DIY for the color Kodachrome process is widely regarded as out of practical reach.)

Comment: Okay, fair enough. (But I still wonder how one can tell the difference between a used and unused film cartridge without developing it. One should believe the little bit of film visible could tell the truth.)

Answer (score 2):

You actually can have this developed.  My husband and I are in the same boat. We also are wondering if the cartridge is processed or unprocessed.  But, there is a company called Film Rescue that can develop this.  It just cannot be developed in color, only black and white.

Comment: It can even be home developed in standard black and white developer, but it's easy to scratch the film during development and drying it.